# AutoFilter all columns after every Search / Userform VBA

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a workbook that every time it opens, clears the workbook from any filter that it has, which it works. But i want to implement so, every time a search is done, the filter that was applied on that workbook is cleared. It's giving me an error which i can't solve.

I tried also doing `If Sheets("Datos").AutoFilterMode then Sheets("Datos").AutoFilterMode = False` but gives me another error.

Further on this, every time the second if its activated, the textbox which should fill the number of total rows that are filtered by surname, does not show anything, but it does when it applies the first if, which is the user ID. (If its needed to be asked on another topic, just miss this paragraph)

```
Private Sub btnBuscar4_Click()
    'declarar las variables
    Dim FindRow
    Dim LastRow As Integer, i As Integer
    Dim cRow As String
    Dim Datos As Worksheet: Set Datos = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Bonito\Desktop\Plataforma\Datos.xlsm").Worksheets("Datos")

    'Aplica la liberación de las hojas para consultarlas
    SheetProtection

    'Si hay filtros, los elimina de la hoja Datos
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

    'Windows("Datos.xlsm").Visible = False 'Hace que no se muestre el excel externo (Datos)

    'hold in memory and stop screen flicker
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'error block
    On Error GoTo errHandler:

        'Filtrar solo por Legajo
        If Me.BLeg3 <> "" Then

        'Guardar el legajo en una variable
        cRow = Me.BLeg3.Value

        Worksheets("Datos").Range("A:A").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=cRow

        LastRow = Sheets("Datos").Range("A500").End(xlUp).Row - 1 'Hay que restarle uno para sacar el titulo

        For i = 2 To LastRow
        If Cells(i, 1) = cRow Then
        Reg2.Value = LastRow 'Muestra la cantidad de filas filtradas de ese legajo
        End If
        Next i

        'Encontrar la fila con la data
        Set FindRow = Datos.Range("A:A").Find(What:=cRow, LookIn:=xlValues)
        Me.CurrentAddress = FindRow.Address 'te trae la celda actual

        'agregar los valores a las casillas correspondientes
        Leg3.Value = FindRow
        Fech3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 4)
        Ape3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 1)
        Nomb3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 2)
        Pues3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 3)
        ComboLiqui3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 5)
        FechaDesde3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 6)
        FechaHasta3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 7)
        Dia3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 12)
        Dia4.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 13)
        Cant3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 8)
        Obs3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 9)

        'Filtrar solo por Apellido
        ElseIf Me.BApe3 <> "" Then

        'Encontrar la fila con la data
        cRow = Me.BApe3.Value

        Worksheets("Datos").Range("B:B").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=cRow

        LastRow = Sheets("Datos").Range("B500").End(xlUp).Row - 1 'Hay que restarle uno para sacar el titulo / Se va hasta la ultima row y automaticamente sube al comienzo

        For i = 2 To LastRow
        If Cells(i, 1) = cRow Then
        Reg2.Value = LastRow 'Muestra la cantidad de filas filtradas de ese legajo
        End If
        Next i

        Set FindRow = Datos.Range("B:B").Find(What:=cRow, LookIn:=xlValues)
        Me.CurrentAddress = FindRow.Address 'te trae la celda actual

        'agregar los valores a las casillas correspondientes
        Leg3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, -1)
        Fech3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 3)
        Ape3.Value = FindRow
        Nomb3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 1)
        Pues3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 2)
        ComboLiqui3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 4)
        FechaDesde3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 5)
        FechaHasta3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 6)
        Dia3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 11)
        Dia4.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 12)
        Cant3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 7)
        Obs3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 8)

    Else
        MsgBox "Por favor, ingresar un Legajo o un Apellido"
    End If

    'error block
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
errHandler:
    MsgBox "Error! Verificar los datos ingresados, porque no son correctos!" & vbCrLf & Err.Description

End Sub
```

Comment: I am trying to run your code, What is SheetProtection  ?  a subroutine that removes protection ?

Comment: Yes, take it out, cuz it just removes the password from the sheet.

Comment: OK I got your code to run, what is the problem, is it reg2 value ?

Comment: It does filter, but every time i want to clear any filters on the table and apply a new one, it doesn't work. I tried clearing any filters when the workbook opened but there is another error... so im stuck..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't count the number of filtered rows with End(xlUp).Row. You need to use SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count. I don't understand the problem with the filter as it works for me. Try

```vb
Private Sub btnBuscar4_Click()

    Const DATA = "C:\Users\Bonito\Desktop\Plataforma\Datos.xlsm"

    'declarar las variables
    Dim rngToFilter As Range
    Dim FindRow As Range
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim cRow As String
    Dim Datos As Worksheet
    Set Datos = Workbooks.Open(DATA).Worksheets("Datos")

    'Aplica la liberaci?n de las hojas para consultarlas
    'SheetProtection

    'Si hay filtros, los elimina de la hoja Datos
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

    'Windows("Datos.xlsm").Visible = False 'Hace que no se muestre el excel externo (Datos)
    'Makes external excel not show (Data)

    'hold in memory and stop screen flicker
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    If Me.bLeg3 <> "" And Me.bApe3 <> "" Then
        ' Please, enter a File or a Last Name
        MsgBox "Por favor, ingresar un Legajo o un Apellido"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'error block
    On Error GoTo errHandler:

    'Filtrar solo por Legajo
    If Me.bLeg3 <> "" Then

        'Guardar el legajo en una variable
        cRow = Me.bLeg3.Value
        LastRow = Sheets("Datos").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rngToFilter = Worksheets("Datos").Range("A1:A" & LastRow)

    'Filtrar solo por Apellido
    ElseIf Me.bApe3 <> "" Then

        'Encontrar la fila con la data
        cRow = Me.bApe3.Value
        LastRow = Sheets("Datos").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rngToFilter = Worksheets("Datos").Range("B1:B" & LastRow)

    End If

    ' count filtered rows
    rngToFilter.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=cRow
    Reg2.Value = rngToFilter.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1

    Set FindRow = rngToFilter.Find(What:=cRow, LookIn:=xlValues)
    Me.CurrentAddress = FindRow.Address 'te trae la celda actual

    'agregar los valores a las casillas correspondientes
    Call SheetToForm(FindRow)

    'error block
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
errHandler:
   ' Verify the data entered, because they are not correct
    MsgBox "Error! Verificar los datos ingresados, porque no son correctos!" & vbCrLf & Err.Description

End Sub


Sub SheetToForm(rng As Range)

    Dim map As Variant, i As Integer
    map = Array(0, "Leg3", 1, "Ape3", 2, "Nomb3", 3, "Pues3", _
                4, "Fech3", 5, "ComboLiqui3", 6, "FechaDesde3", 7, "FechaHasta3", _
                8, "Cant3", 9, "Obs3", 12, "Dia3", 13, "Dia4")

    For i = LBound(map) To UBound(map) Step 2
        Me.Controls(map(i + 1)).Value = rng.Columns(1).Offset(0, map(i))
    Next

    Me.CurrentAddress = rng.Address 'te trae la celda actual

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, i´m gonna test it and give you my feedback if it works.

Comment: It does work the filter, but it does not clear before doing a second search, which i´m struggling with.

Comment: Do you mean on another btnBuscar4_Click ?

Comment: Yes. I first tried to do it every time the `datos.xlsm` opened to clear any filter that was saved, but i prefer after every search. Or both if possible, because in both cases, it gives me an error

Comment: In your current code, it does not even apply the line of clearing the filters.

Comment: How do you know ? Every btnBuscar4_Click clears the filters and then applies the new one.

Comment: Seems working now, i added the same code on the workbook that opens to be able to clear any filter that remained when i add new data. Thanks